# How to add all contentNames to a list by making scroll down with Android mobile, selenium?

Tags: java, android, selenium, mobile

I need your help. There are some content_episodes and Im trying to get all of them to a list.in my codes I can take a few of them,but then Im trying to scrolldown and take the remains of them,it fails.I can take only episodes which comes not doing scrolldown.How can I take the remains of content_episodes by making scroldown? Then, I will compare the list between Webservice list .

```
System.out.println("---------Uygulamadan Gelen Bölümler----------");
    while (scrollEndEpisode == false) {
        List<MobileElement> episodeListFromApp = getElement(DPConstans.LISTVIEW_EPISODES).findElements(DPConstans.TXTEPISODENAME);
        if(episodeListFromApp.size()>0) {
        if (episodeListFromApp.get(episodeListFromApp.size() - 1).getText().equals(lastEpisode)) {
            scrollEndEpisode = true;
            break;
        }
        for (MobileElement mobileElement : episodeListFromApp) {
            int index = mobileElement.getText().indexOf(".");
            String epsiodeName = mobileElement.getText().substring(index + 2, mobileElement.getText().length());
            System.out.println(epsiodeName);
            episodeNamesFromApp.add(epsiodeName);
        }
        waitSeconds(5);
        lastEpisode = episodeListFromApp.get(episodeListFromApp.size() - 1).getText();
        swipeDownAccordingToPhoneSize();


    compareNameList(episodeNamesFromApp, "Uygulama", episodeNamesFromWebService, "Web Servis");
    }
    else {
        Assert.assertTrue("İçeriğe ait bölümler bulunamadı.", false);
    }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Problem is this line:

```
compareNameList(episodeNamesFromApp, "Uygulama", episodeNamesFromWebService, "Web Servis");
```

This line must be out of the while loop.